# javascript variable with apex variable error

Tags: apex, javascript

```
{!Account.contacts[i].Lastname}
```

where `i` is Javascript loop variable.

> ERROR : Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.i'

Comment: can you please add the code.

Answer (score 3):

I presume this is a Visualforce page.

This expression:

```
{!Account.contacts[i].Lastname}
```

is processed at the server-side where any values used such as `i` must exist as properties on the Apex controller. Once that processing is done, the resulting HTML is passed to the client-side (the browser) where there can also be a JavaScript variable `i`.

Best to think more about what you are trying to achieve keeping the server-side/client-side distinction in mind.